# Open native AirPlay mirroring menu

Tags: ios, swift, airplay

How can I create a button outside of a MediaPlayer which can be used to open the native AirPlay mirroring menu? If you look at the Spotify app they have a button which is used to open Apples native menu.

How can I achieve this myself?

Spotify: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPNiX.png